# How to do text processing using awk to cut last field in a line?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I am having this scenario and need if I can improvise the awk output.

1. cat example.txt

   ```
   "id": "/subscriptions/fbfa3437-c63c-4ed7-b9d3-fe595221950d/resourceGroups/rg-ooty/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/fb11b768-4d9f-4e83-b7dc-ee677f496fc9",
   "id": "/subscriptions/fbfa3437-c63c-4ed7-b9d3-fe595221950d/resourceGroups/rg-ooty/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/fbee83e8-a84a-4b22-8197-fc9cc924801f",
   "id": "/subscriptions/fbfa3437-c63c-4ed7-b9d3-fe595221950d/resourceGroups/rg-ooty/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/fc224f83-57f4-41eb-aee3-78f18d055704",
   ```
2. I am looking to cut the pattern after /virtualMachines/
3. Hence, used the below awk command to get the output.

   ```
   cat example.txt | awk '{print $2}' | awk -F"/" '{print $(NF)}' | awk -F'",' '{print $1}'
   fb11b768-4d9f-4e83-b7dc-ee677f496fc9
   fbee83e8-a84a-4b22-8197-fc9cc924801f
   fc224f83-57f4-41eb-aee3-78f18d055704
   ```
4. Is there any way I can use some options like 'getline' or multiple awk options in single awk execution or better ways to improve the command to get the output?

Please suggest.

Comment: Good that you have shown your efforts in post, please try to select an answer(after you see some answers in your post) as a correct answer too to complete the thread.

Comment: If this is JSON I suggest to use [jq](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jq/info).

Answer (score 3):

Use `"` and `/` as field separators and print second last field:

```
awk -F '["/]' '{print $(NF-1)}' file
```

Output:

```
fb11b768-4d9f-4e83-b7dc-ee677f496fc9
fbee83e8-a84a-4b22-8197-fc9cc924801f
fc224f83-57f4-41eb-aee3-78f18d055704
```

Answer (score 1):

If the spacing of *example.txt* is as consistent as it seems, then it's simpler to use `cut` with the `-c`*haracters* count option:

```
cut -c 127-162 example.txt
```

Output:

```
fb11b768-4d9f-4e83-b7dc-ee677f496fc9
fbee83e8-a84a-4b22-8197-fc9cc924801f
fc224f83-57f4-41eb-aee3-78f18d055704
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use sed for this:

```
sed 's#.*/\([^/]*\)",#\1#' example.txt
```

Matches anything `.*` forwardslash `/` then captures `\(` any number of non-forwardslash characters `[^/]*`, ends the capture `\)` followed by a quote & comma to end `",`, and replaces this with the captured group (anything between the forwardslash and the `",` at the end.